# Pig casting / datatypes

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, avro

I'm trying to dump relation into AVRO file but I'm getting a strange error:

```
org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

I don't use `DataByteArray` (bytearray), see description of the relation below.

```
sensitiveSet: {rank_ID: long,name: chararray,customerId: long,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray}
```

Even when I do explicit casting I get the same error:

```
sensitiveSet = foreach sensitiveSet generate (long) $0, (chararray) $1, (long) $2, (chararray) $3, (chararray) $4, (chararray) $5, (chararray) $6;

STORE sensitiveSet INTO 'testOut2222.avro'
USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage('no_schema_check', 'schema', '{"type":"record","name":"xxxx","namespace":"","fields":[{"name":"rank_ID","type":"long"},{"name":"name","type":"string","store":"no","sensitive":"na"},{"name":"customerId","type":"string","store":"yes","sensitive":"yes"},{"name":"VIN","type":"string","store":"yes","sensitive":"yes"},{"name":"birth_date","type":"string","store":"yes","sensitive":"no"},{"name":"fuel_mileage","type":"string","store":"yes","sensitive":"no"},{"name":"fuel_consumption","type":"string","store":"yes","sensitive":"no"}]}');
```

EDITED:

I'm trying to define an output schema which should be a Tuple that contains another two tuples, i.e. `stats:tuple(c:tuple(),d:tuple)`.

The code below doesn't work as it was intended. It somehow produces structure as:

```
stats:tuple(b:tuple(c:tuple(),d:tuple()))
```

Below is output produced by `describe`.

```
sourceData: {com.mortardata.pig.dataspliter_36: (stats: ((name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray),(name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray)))}
```

Is it possible to create structure as below, which means I need to remove the tuple b from the previous example.

```
grunt> describe sourceData;
sourceData: {t: (s: (name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray),n: (name: chararray,customerId: chararray,VIN: chararray,birth_date: chararray,fuel_mileage: chararray,fuel_consumption: chararray))}
```

The below code doesn't work as expected.

```
  public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
    Schema sensTuple = new Schema();
    sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("name", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("customerId", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("VIN", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("birth_date", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_mileage", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    sensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_consumption", DataType.CHARARRAY));

    Schema nonSensTuple = new Schema();
    nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("name", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("customerId", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("VIN", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("birth_date", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_mileage", DataType.CHARARRAY));
    nonSensTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("fuel_consumption", DataType.CHARARRAY));


    Schema parentTuple = new Schema();
    parentTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, sensTuple, DataType.TUPLE));
    parentTuple.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, nonSensTuple, DataType.TUPLE));


    Schema outputSchema = new Schema();
    outputSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("stats", parentTuple, DataType.TUPLE));

    return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input), outputSchema, DataType.TUPLE));
```

The UDF's exec method returns:

```
public Tuple exec(Tuple tuple) throws IOException {    
  Tuple parentTuple  = mTupleFactory.newTuple();
  parentTuple.append(tuple1);
  parentTuple.append(tuple2);
```

EDIT2 (FIXED)

```
...
Schema outputSchema = new Schema();
outputSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("stats", parentTuple, DataType.TUPLE));
```

<del>return new Schema (new Schema.FieldSchema (getSchemaName (this.getClass ().getName ().toLowerCase (), input), outputSchema, DataType.TUPLE);</del>

```
return outputSchema;
```

Now I return proper schema from UDF where all items are chararray but when I try to store those items into avro file as type: string I got the same error:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
```

SOLVED:
Ok, the issue was that data wasnt casted to the proper type inside the UDF body - exec () method. Looks like it works now!

Comment: Have you tried just using `USING ...AvroStorage()` or `...AvroStorage('no_schema_check')` ?

Comment: as you can see "no_chema_check" is there.

Comment: @heap: customerId is of long type and in avro its getting saved as string, should it not be of type long ?

Comment: @Murali in the first example its as long, in second example where i cast everything into chararray its as a string.

Comment: Are you using any other UDFs before storing?  Sometimes the schema isn't preserved by a UDF and the resulting type is DataByteArray.  Also sometimes a UDF may produce a different type than is actually reported by the schema (due to a bug).

Comment: I use UDF before storing. Is there a way how to properly cast fields returned from the udf? Should i use "AS" as part of the statement where i call UDF or do i have to handle it somehow internally inside UDF? Is the bug somewhere reported? Thank you!

Comment: I do see that no_schema_check is there. I'm saying have you tried running it without passing the schema and just using the no_schema_check option or else no options at all?

Comment: @wattsinabox it was fixed, see updated entry.

Comment: I'm glad your issue is fixed. Please either accept the answer from @matterhayes or add your own answer below and accept it so that this question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you are using a UDF that isn't preserving the schema, or somewhere it is getting lost. I believe DataByteArray is the fallback type when the real type isn't known. You may need to add a caste to workaround this, however a better solution is to fix whatever UDF is dropping the schema.

Comment: Which means i have to define outputSchema method inside my UDF. Im wondering how its possible to define one tuple that contains inside another two tuples.

Comment: Ok, i fixed the ouputSchema code, now it returns proper schema but it doesnt work... same error all the time when I try to store records into avro file. java.lang.Exception: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)

Comment: So im 100% sure that UDF returns chararray, isnt it pig bug?

Comment: Ok, the issue was that data wasnt casted to the proper type inside the UDF body - exec() method. Looks like it works now!